# Extracting zip files with Powershell failing on last zip file.

Tags: powershell, scripting, zip

I'm trying to unzip multiple zip files within a directory using a Powershell script. Everything goes well, except it always fails during the last zip file in the directory. The zip file isn't corrupt - I can manually unzip it just fine. It starts extracting the contents (I can see it being populated in Windows Explorer), but then towards the end it fails, removes the extracted contents from that zip file from Windows Explorer, and throws out the following error:

```
Exception calling "ExtractToFile" with "3" argument(s). "Could not find a part of the path '<path-to-a-file-within-the-zip-archive>.
```

I'm unsure of why this is happening when all of the other zips unzip just fine. I've also found out that this does not happen whenever I extract the files to the same directory as the Powershell script that is executing this code.

Here is my code that unzips the files:

```
 Get-ChildItem .\ZipFilesDirectory-Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath .\ExtractedZipFolders -Force
```

Comment: Shots in the dark. Is it failing on the last file or always on the last one in the folder? What happens when you process them individually. ie not in a pipe. Does anything change if you use absolute paths instead of relative ones?

Comment: Is it a problem with that archive, or a problem with your script?  I.e., does another archive error if you remove the offending one?  Could any of the other archives be creating a file that the last archive wants to create as a folder?

Comment: It always fails on the last zip file within the folder - I can't determine which file it fails on within that zip though. Processing them individually works fine.  Since this script is intended to run on different computers, using absolute paths is not an option.

Comment: @BaconBits Hmm. Removing that zip resulted in a clean extraction. Based on that I would guess something may be wrong with that zip, however, that wouldn't explain why I can unzip it perfectly fine by unzipping to the same location as the Powershell script.

Comment: Try extracting the files in a different order.  Like `Get-ChildItem .\ZipFilesDirectory -Filter *.zip | Sort Name -Descending | Expand-Archive ...`.

Comment: So I made powershell extract the zips using 7z instead and the same file threw an error. So, I'm guessing there is something wrong with that file that Powershell doesn't like. 7z however at least continues extracting and the extracted contents stay in the appropriate directory.

Comment: _Since this script is intended to run on different computers, using absolute paths is not an option_. That should not matter since the script knows where it is running. Does not matter in this case since you know what the issue is or at least where to start. FYI Things like resolve-path and convert-path can get you absolute from relative paths.

Comment: Turns out the there was a file in that zip archive that was too long resulting in a "Path too long" issue.

Comment: @Roka545 You should add that as the answer and mark your question as answered.  That is allowed on the site, and preferable to leaving a question unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there was a file in my zip archive that resulted in a "Path too long" issue when extracting to the desired directory. As a workaround, I extracted the archive to my C drive (C:/), then moved it to the proper directory.